# TimeoutException using EC.text_to_be_present_in_element with phantomjs

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using Python 2.7.13, Selenium version 3.3.3 and PhantomJS 2.1.1 downloaded from https://phantomjs.org.

If I run the following script on Fedora 25 (or Windows 7) it runs fine with Firefox but raises a  `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` with PhantomJS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest2

FF = True
#FF = False

class Test(unittest2.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        if FF:
            binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
            d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
            self.driver.maximize_window()

        self.base_url = "http://phantomjs.org/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
        self.result = 0

    def test01(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)

        print("Check http://phantomjs.org/ title")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"), "PhantomJS | PhantomJS")
        )

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest2.main(failfast=True)
```

With Firefox:

```
$ python test.py
Check http://phantomjs.org/ title
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 9.433s

OK
```

With PhantomJS:

```
$ python test.py
Check http://phantomjs.org/ title
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test01 (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in test01
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"), "PhantomJS | PhantomJS")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 21.169s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing

```
EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "/html/head/title"), "PhantomJS | PhantomJS")
```

to

```
EC.title_contains("PhantomJS | PhantomJS")
```

This was one of the library calls listed in the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)